# Initialize public Class Member Array from outside the Class

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

what I want to do is really basic, I think. To code example shows it clearly.

```
class MyClass{
     public string[] Bar;
}

MyClass Foo = new MyClass();
Foo.Bar = { "word", "word", "word" };
```

This code gives me an error in Visual Studio C#. *(Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement)*

Is there a better way to provide an array to the class? The array could be `const` for my part.

**How can I provide an (const) array to a class from outside?**

I don't want to use the constructor, because the array should be optionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only initialize arrays using the `{}` *without the `new` operator* as part of a declaration (which in turn has to explicitly specify the array type). This has nothing to do with whether it's in the same class or not:

```
int[] x = { 1, 2, 3 }; // Fine
x = { 4, 5, 6 }; // Fail
x = new[] { 7, 8, 9 }; // Implicitly typed array as of C# 3
x = new int[] { 10, 11, 12 }; // Works with all versions of C#
```

See sections 12.6 (array initializers), 10.5 (field declarations), 8.5.1 (local variable declarations) and 7.6.10.4 (array creation expressions) of the C# 4 specification for details.

To answer your comment on Darin's post: no, there's no such thing as a "const" array in any sense I can imagine you mean. Even if you make the array variable readonly, like this:

```
private static readonly int[] Values = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

that only makes the *variable* read-only. `Values` will always refer to the same array object (which will therefore always have 3 elements) but arrays themselves are always mutable. If you want to build a read-only collection, I'd suggest using [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx), probably via [List.AsReadOnly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx):

```
private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<int> Values =
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }.AsReadOnly();
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct [array initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573.aspx) syntax is:

```
Foo.Bar = new[] { "word", "word", "word" };
```

You can use `{ "word", "word", "word" }` only if you explicitly have specified the type on the left hand-side:

```
string[] foo = { "word", "word", "word" };
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But is there a way to make a **const** array?

Comment: @sharethis, what do you mean by const array?

Comment: It could be a constant for performance reasons. I don't want to change it again.

Comment: You should not use a field in this case. You could use a property with a public getter (allowing to read it from the outside) but with a private setter (allowing to modify only from the inside of the class). Thus you could have your class take the array as constructor parameter and store it in the backing field of the property. This way the array will be initialized once.

Comment: If you want initialize in constructor is not necessary to have property (with backing field), you can have just field.

Answer (score 1):

You should create array, Also you can do this initialization in Foo creation:

```
MyClass Foo = new MyClass{Bar = new []{ "word", "word", "word" }};
```

If you want initialize your array only once define it as readonly, and do initialization in constructor:

```
class MyClass{
     public readonly string[] Bar;
     public MyClass(string[] bar)
        {
            Bar = bar;
        }
}

MyClass Foo = new MyClass (new[] { "word", "word", "word" } );
```

**Edit:** If you don't like initialize it in your constructor, you can use semi [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) like pattern:

```
class MyClass
{
    private static string[] bar;
    public static string[] Bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
        set
        {
            if (bar == null)
                bar = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But if you add `lock` statement it will be thread safe but may be performance decreases.

Answer (score 0):

add new[] before brackets:

```
    Foo.Bar = new[] { "word", "word", "word" };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a const array and initialize it anywhere other than its declaration. You can make a `readonly` array which can be initialized in the constructor. If you want to set the array's value somewhere else, it needs to be an ordinary data field.